# Fonts Look Square Instead of alphabets unity 5.6

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Watch Image]

Watch this Fonts Why This is happen this is happen me in many projects.
All the texts are Sqaure boxes

Comment: Giant font size, scaled tiny, means all of the antialiasing goes away. Don't scale your text objects.

Comment: Can you check what shader is used by the material on this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your font size is 100. Because of this, your text will be very large. Set your font size to 5 or something like that.